# How to get text as with innerText, but working in all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I want to extract text of a twitter Follow button in, for example, https://twitter.com/Google/followers

When I use `document.getElementsByClassName("user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button")[0].innerText`, it displays the text correctly that is:

> Follow
>   Follow @Google

... and when I am following the user, it shows

> Following
>   Following @Google

However, I can't use `innerText` as it is not supported by old versions of Firefox, so I looked into using `textContent`:

But when I use `document.getElementsByClassName("user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button")[0].textContent` instead it displays the following irrespective of the fact that I am following the user or not:-

> Follow
>   Follow @Google
>
> Following
>   Following @Google
>
> Unfollow
>   Unfollow @Google
>
> Blocked
>   Blocked @Google
>
> Unblock
>   Unblock @Google
>
> Pending
>   Pending follow request from @Google
>
> Cancel
>   Cancel your follow request to @Google

How can I make sure that it displays the text like `innerText` so that I can know if I am following user or not?

Here is some HTML Code of the button:-

```
<span class="user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button">
  <button type="button" class="
    EdgeButton
    EdgeButton--secondary

    EdgeButton--medium 
    button-text
    follow-text">
      <span aria-hidden="true">Follow</span>
      <span class="u-hiddenVisually">Follow <span class="username u-dir u-textTruncate" dir="ltr">@<b>Google</b></span></span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="
    EdgeButton
    EdgeButton--primary

    EdgeButton--medium 
    button-text
    following-text">
      <span aria-hidden="true">Following</span>
      <span class="u-hiddenVisually">Following <span class="username u-dir u-textTruncate" dir="ltr">@<b>Google</b></span></span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="
    EdgeButton
    EdgeButton--danger

    EdgeButton--medium 
    button-text
    unfollow-text">
      <span aria-hidden="true">Unfollow</span>
      <span class="u-hiddenVisually">Unfollow <span class="username u-dir u-textTruncate" dir="ltr">@<b>Google</b></span></span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="
    EdgeButton
    EdgeButton--invertedDanger

    EdgeButton--medium 
    button-text
    blocked-text">
    <span aria-hidden="true">Blocked</span>
    <span class="u-hiddenVisually">Blocked <span class="username u-dir u-textTruncate" dir="ltr">@<b>Google</b></span></span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="
    EdgeButton
    EdgeButton--danger

    EdgeButton--medium 
    button-text
    unblock-text">
    <span aria-hidden="true">Unblock</span>
    <span class="u-hiddenVisually">Unblock <span class="username u-dir u-textTruncate" dir="ltr">@<b>Google</b></span></span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="
    EdgeButton
    EdgeButton--secondary

    EdgeButton--medium 
    button-text
    pending-text">
    <span aria-hidden="true">Pending</span>
    <span class="u-hiddenVisually">Pending follow request from <span class="username u-dir u-textTruncate" dir="ltr">@<b>Google</b></span></span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="
    EdgeButton
    EdgeButton--secondary

    EdgeButton--medium 
    button-text
    cancel-text">
    <span aria-hidden="true">Cancel</span>
    <span class="u-hiddenVisually">Cancel your follow request to <span class="username u-dir u-textTruncate" dir="ltr">@<b>Google</b></span></span>
  </button>
</span>
```

Comment: Please provide some HTML. The link should not be necessary to have all info to the question (and in this case one even needs a twitter account).

Comment: Sure, should I provide whole HTML or specific HTML containing that part of code?

Comment: Only what is necessary to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Okay! Updated some HTML Code in the question.. But, formatting is somewhat weird..

Comment: Is it okay? Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, used Pastebin..

Comment: It would be better to embed the HTML in your question (formatted as code -- use the `{}` button in the edit box), but it is already better. However, that HTML example seems to hide everything? Which button would be visible in this example?

Comment: In this, it is showing "Following" in the Twitter Page.. Don't know much of HTML.. I can post whole code of Page, if its okay?

Comment: No, I would not do that. Just make sure that the "class" part of the HTML is always correct. Currently it is the same for "Follow" and "Following". That does not seem right.

Comment: When I hover in the Following, it shows Unfollow.. Do you mean class of buttons?

Comment: For Follow button, it is:-    EdgeButton
   EdgeButton--secondary
   
   EdgeButton--medium
   button-text
   follow-text

And for Following, it is this-

EdgeButton
   EdgeButton--primary
   
   EdgeButton--medium
   button-text
   following-text

The last part of class is different.. (Follow-text and Following-text), it this is what you mean?

Comment: The thing is that site shows this same exact HTML code even when the button says Follow and when it is showing Following.. But, innerText is able to get the text correctly..

Comment: Yes, it could be that, but without the actual CSS definition of those classes it is not possible to know which actually hide the text. I have posted an answer which should do the job if the classes indeed determine which text to show and which not. It could however be that the twitter page hides the text with some additional JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your own implementation of `innerText` which should not include text that is hidden. As you tagged the question with jQuery, you could make it a jQuery plug in, by defining `$.fn.innerText` like this:

```js
$.fn.innerText = function () {
    return (function recurse($nodes) {
        return $.map($nodes, function (node) {
            return node.nodeType === 3 ? node.nodeValue
                : $(node).is(":hidden") ? ""
                : recurse($(node).contents());
        }).join("");
    })(this);
}

const texts = $.map($(".user-actions-follow-button"), function(elem) {
    return $(elem).innerText().trim();
});
console.log(texts);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="user-actions-follow-button">
    <span style="display: none;">Follow @me</span>
    <span style="display: ;">Following @me</span>
</span>

<span class="user-actions-follow-button">
    <span style="display: ;">Follow @her</span>
    <span style="display: none;">Following @her</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working! But, just a question is it possible to make this code in Javascript? I want to just get the text of first element for example so in Javascript I would simply do [0] and for second [1] and so on..

Comment: Yes, that is possible, and certainly also with jQuery. See the update of the answer.

Comment: Thanks! But, just a question..
For example:- I define innerText() using the code above..

Then, when I use document.getElementsByClassName("user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button")[0].innerText(), it says that Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0].innerText is not a function..

So, is this normal? That is do I have to use jQuery only to make the text thing work? It would be nice if I can do this solely using JavaScript, that is if possible..

Also, thanks a lot for answering!

Comment: The answer defines the method `innerText` on a jQuery object, so you must get the jQuery object of a selection before using that method: instead of `document.getElementsByClassName("user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button")[0].innerText()` do `$(".user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button").eq(0).innerText()`. But better use the code I have provided. Yes, this needs jQuery, as you tagged your question with it I expected this was OK for you.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot it is working perfectly! :D
If it is okay for ya, can you please let me know why we have to use .user-actions-follow-button  instead of .user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button?

Thanks once again for the answer! :)

Comment: Those classes are separated by spaces, so there are three of them. I only picked one of them that seemed enough to identify these buttons. If you really need those buttons to have all three classes, then you would do something like `$(".user-actions-follow-button").filter(".js-follow-btn").filter(".follow-button")`... with the additional `filter` parts. But in this case I think that would not yield any difference.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks a lot for explaining this! It is really appreciated! :)